# libstdc++ 10.3 doesn't provide <compare>

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, clang++, libstdc++

So I just upgraded to clang 12 because I need `<compare>`, and as soon as I try to recompile I'm hit with

```
./test/math/ordering.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'compare' file not found
#include <compare>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I checked and (according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20) and the [official gnu site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/api.html#api.rel_101)) my version of libstdc++6, 10.3, is supposed to include this header. I'm compiling with this command:

```
clang++-12 ./test/math/ordering.cpp -o ./test/math/ordering.exe -I ./inc/lcu --include testing/assert.h -std=c++20 -stdlib=libstdc++
```

Running it with `-v` prints:

```
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.1-++20210825102835+fed41342a82f-1~exp1~20210825083541.133
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Candidate multilib: x32;@mx32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-12/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name ordering.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/clang/12.0.1 --include testing/assert.h -I ./inc/lcu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/clang/12.0.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -std=c++20 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/lenerdv/projects/games/lib/lcu -ferror-limit 3 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-implicit-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/ordering-c353eb.o -x c++ ./test/math/ordering.cpp
clang -cc1 version 12.0.1 based upon LLVM 12.0.1 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ./inc/lcu
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/clang/12.0.1/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
./test/math/ordering.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'compare' file not found
#include <compare>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, but everything was already up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/`? Only `9`? Do you actually have libstdc++ 10 installed?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes and probably yes. the package itself is named libstdc++6, but the version is 10.3. this threw me off a little, because there are also libstdc++-10-* packages, but they are all either dev, doc or pic packages. anyway, i haven't installed any of them yet

Comment: I think you need a `-dev` package to have the headers? Or you can install GCC 10, then you'll get the right packages as dependencies.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat installing libstdc++-10-dev was enough. if you want to post it as an answer, i'll be happy to accept it